# How can I open a text file with multiple delimiters in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file which I am trying to open in a pandas dataframe however I am not quite sure how to parse the data in such a way that it splits at all of these values.

file is attached here: http://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/ftp/J/A+A/568/A22/tablef3.dat

The readme file that explains the data is attached here:
http://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/ftp/J/A+A/568/A22/ReadMe

As of now i am using:

pd.read_csv(http://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/ftp/J/A+A/568/A22/tablef3.dat)

Once putting the data into pandas I want to also add custom headings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which delimiters did you identify? The dot might be the decimal sign.

Comment: Ah yes you're correct, I will go ahead and edit the question now. Thank you!

Comment: The real problem might be identifying the columns as there seem to be some weirdly arranged numbers in the middle of the data columns. If there is no underlying dataformat I am not aware of, this might become rather tricky at first glance.

Comment: Yes I agree, I've just attached the ReadMe file where is explains the context on the data under the heading 'Byte-by-byte Description of file: tablef3.dat'. The data is laid out in Byte form which is proving tricky to sort.

Comment: I just had a look into the readme and the data file. What they are calling bytes is basically the character index. So, the data file is 193 characters wide. Therefore, a very basic approach would be reading the file line by line and split each line into its column by slicing the line string. This is quite inefficient for long files, but should get you started.

Comment: Ah I see! I will begin trying to do it line by line and also look at the documentation you so kindly provided. Thank you Albert I really appreciate your help.

Comment: In addition, you could use pandas' `read_fwf()` feature and provide the `colspec` according to the data file readme: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.read_fwf`. Extract useful specs from your readme file:

```
colspecs = [(0, 12), (12, 21), (21, 30), (30, 31), (31, 41), (41, 50), (50, 60),
            (60, 69), (69, 79), (79, 88), (88, 98), (98, 108), (108, 121),
            (121, 130), (130, 140), (140, 150), (150, 160), (160, 161), (161, 172),
            (172, 183), (183, 193)]

colnames = ['Name','zcmb', 'hel', 'e_z', 'mb', 'e_mb', 'x1', 'e_x1', 'c', 'e_c',
            'logMst', 'e_logMst', 'tmax', 'e_tmax', 'cov(mbs)', 'cov(mb,c)',
            'cov(s,c)', 'set', 'RAdeg', 'DEdeg', 'bias']

df = pd.read_fwf('http://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/ftp/J/A+A/568/A22/tablef3.dat',
                 colspecs=colspecs, names=colnames)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
Name      zcmb       hel  e_z         mb      e_mb        x1      e_x1         c       e_c  ...  e_logMst          tmax    e_tmax  cov(mbs)  cov(mb,c)  cov(s,c)  set       RAdeg      DEdeg      bias
0      03D1au  0.503084  0.504300    0  23.001698  0.088031  1.273191  0.150058 -0.012353  0.030011  ...  0.110500  52909.745220  0.214332  0.000790   0.000440 -0.000030    1   36.043210  -4.037469  0.001697
1      03D1aw  0.580724  0.582000    0  23.573937  0.090132  0.974346  0.273823 -0.025076  0.036691  ...  0.088000  52902.898002  0.352732  0.002823   0.000415  0.001574    1   36.061634  -4.517158  0.000843
2      03D1ax  0.494795  0.496000    0  22.960139  0.088110 -0.728837  0.102069 -0.099683  0.030305  ...  0.112500  52915.923670  0.111634  0.000542   0.000475 -0.000024    1   36.097287  -4.720774  0.001692
3      03D1bp  0.345928  0.347000    0  22.398137  0.087263 -1.155110  0.112834 -0.040581  0.026679  ...  0.123500  52920.249015  0.102828  0.001114   0.000616  0.000295    1   36.657235  -4.838779 -0.000270
4      03D1co  0.677662  0.679000    0  24.078115  0.098356  0.618820  0.404295 -0.039380  0.067403  ...  0.284000  52954.458342  0.454715  0.011857   0.000780  0.005898    1   36.567748  -4.935050 -0.002855
..        ...       ...       ...  ...        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...  ...       ...           ...       ...       ...        ...       ...  ...         ...        ...       ...
735  sn2007co  0.027064  0.026962    0  16.504006  0.141685 -0.137806  0.061153  0.105288  0.020382  ...  0.280891  54265.212054  0.056635  0.000095   0.000377  0.000007    3  275.765000  29.897050 -0.009803
736  sn2007cq  0.025468  0.025918    0  15.797848  0.143429 -0.657941  0.115645 -0.060805  0.025820  ...  0.280891  54281.025669  0.070944  0.000392   0.000639  0.000075    3  333.668430   5.080160 -0.009575
737   sn2007f  0.023810  0.023590    0  15.895501  0.144315  0.618766  0.041400 -0.055411  0.026006  ...  0.118500  54124.058397  0.045234 -0.000055   0.000645 -0.000180    3  195.812750  50.618760 -0.009361
738  sn2007qe  0.023867  0.024000    0  16.068268  0.144350  0.760605  0.045650  0.052186  0.026200  ...  5.000000  54429.852171  0.037486  0.000101   0.000654 -0.000076    3  358.553990  27.409170 -0.009368
739  sn2008bf  0.022068  0.021275    0  15.718540  0.144685  0.430639  0.068523 -0.038367  0.021262  ...  0.156500  54555.109466  0.090470  0.000136   0.000409 -0.000104    3  181.011990  20.245080 -0.009159

[740 rows x 21 columns]
```

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 740 entries, 0 to 739
Data columns (total 21 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   Name       740 non-null    object 
 1   zcmb       740 non-null    float64
 2   hel        740 non-null    float64
 3   e_z        740 non-null    int64  
 4   mb         740 non-null    float64
 5   e_mb       740 non-null    float64
 6   x1         740 non-null    float64
 7   e_x1       740 non-null    float64
 8   c          740 non-null    float64
 9   e_c        740 non-null    float64
 10  logMst     740 non-null    float64
 11  e_logMst   740 non-null    float64
 12  tmax       740 non-null    float64
 13  e_tmax     740 non-null    float64
 14  cov(mbs)   740 non-null    float64
 15  cov(mb,c)  740 non-null    float64
 16  cov(s,c)   740 non-null    float64
 17  set        740 non-null    int64  
 18  RAdeg      740 non-null    float64
 19  DEdeg      740 non-null    float64
 20  bias       740 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(18), int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 121.5+ KB
```

Comment: Thank you Corralien for taking the time out to answer my question! I really appreciate all your help!!